# Passing a variable to a method at runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I am working on a windows store app. In my application, I want to create a pushpin and a method for the pushpin.tapped event at runtime. My aim is to pass a variable to the puhpin_Tapped method and show that variable's value with a message dialog. Here is my code:

```
    Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
    pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, loc);
    pushpin.Name = sd.name;
    pushpin.Tapped +=pushpin_Tapped(pushpin.Name);
    map.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

And here is my pushpin_Tapped method:

```
    private async void pushpin_Tapped(string _name)
    {
        MessageDialog myMessage = new MessageDialog(_name);
        await myMessage.ShowAsync();
    }
```

However, when I write these code blocks, there occurs an error as "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedEventHandler' " drawing a red line underneath "pushpin_Tapped(pushpin.Name)".

So what is it that I am doing wrong? Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private async void pushpin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog myMessage = new MessageDialog(((Pushpin)sender).Name);
    await myMessage.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void pushpin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        MessageDialog myMessage = new MessageDialog(pushpin.Name);
        await myMessage.ShowAsync();
     }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because I defined the "pushpin" variable within a method. It cant be used in other methods without being defined.

Comment: Eventhandler should have pattern (sender, eventargs). But you can call it using (null, null). For passing argument pushpin.Name, perhaps you have to declare class variable...

Comment: Even no need for a class varible. I added the statement "var tappedPin = sender as Pushpin;" to the top of the pushpin_Tapped method, and now it works fine. Thanks for your suggestion.